# How many scientists can survive?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Yesterday the aliens took 100 scientists from Earth as prisoners. They want to test how smart the humans are.

The aliens made 101 headbands, numbered from 1 to 101. On the contest day, they throw away one of the headbands, and then from the remaining headbands randomly put one on each of the scientists. Then they line up the scientists in a queue in such a way that each person can see the numbers written on the headbands of the people who stand in front of him, but can't see his/her own number, nor the number of the scientists behind him.

Then the aliens will force the scientists to guess their numbers, and after everybody finished saying a number, they will kill those who said a number different from what is written on their headbands. Note that each scientist can only say one number in the range 1-101, and no one can say a number that has already been said. Each scientist can independently choose when to speak their guess; there is no pre-set order on when they have to speak. As you are very smart, the scientists asked you to find a way to save the most of them. Find this way, and then prove it.

Comment: The scientist at the very back of the queque can see 99 numbers, that one should speak first , naming 1 of the 2 numbers he can't see with a 50% chance of saving themselves. After that the next to last scientist can see 98 numbers and knows they can't say the number chosen by the first scientist, so he also can choose from only 2 options. Continuing the process to the front of the queque each scientist will have a 50% chance of survival. This method would expect to save half of them, (but might possibly save none of them)  I can't see how they could do any better.

Comment: @WW1 Iv heard that there is a way to save 99 scientists! But I don't know how

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4pocYXOmTQ

Comment: That problem seems very similar.

Comment: must the number said by a scientist be a number between $1$ and $101$?

Comment: Is there any forced order in which the scientist needs to say a number, or can they answer in any order? Does each scientist die immediately after having said their number, or are they killed after ALL numbers have been said?

Comment: @IQAndreas A solution that guarantees the survival of at least 99 requires that the first one who speaks is the one who sees the numbers of all others. Also, the problem states that they are killed after ALL numbers have been said.

Comment: As a simpler problem, one might want to first figure out how to save 2/3 scientists instead of 99/100.

Comment: @Quincunx For the first question, I'm playing with an idea for how to save people by changing the ordering of answering. And for the second question, I just wanted to double check that the _"after everybody finished saying a number"_ wasn't a mistranslation.

Comment: In what order are the scientists asked? When one scientist is asked, do all the other scientists hear his answer?

Comment: I would contest that this is a much better fit for [Puzzling.SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a much better fit on puzzling.se (once the missing details are clarified).

Comment: This question should stay here. It's an interesting math problem. (In my limited experience, too many of the puzzles on puzzling.SE rely on lateral thinking.)

Comment: I would also like to see this stay open.  It's an interesting problem IMO.

Comment: This looks like a clear cut example of what belongs on the puzzling SE. Whether a problem belongs there has nothing to do with whether it's 'lateral' thinking or not, there are plenty of math questions there too.  I also want to point out to OP that they have yet to update the problem statement with the requirement that the scientists can only say numbers from 1 to 101.  Imo, it's unreasonable to say the scientists _can't_ say numbers larger than 101 on the basis that scientists can apparently process video encodings in binary per @Gamamal's comments....

Comment: @Ryan On puzzling SE, questions must carefully exclude all possible lateral thinking tricks to avoid allowing lateral thinking answers.  Here on math SE, any lateral thinking answer is automatically off-topic.  I find that a great improvement for these "puzzles" that are really about mathematical optimization.

Comment: they may want to test for smartness but it seems they are actually testing whether you can do what they appear to think you should. Conforming to this obediently may or may not be a smart thing enough to do. Albeit it would take aliens smarter than you (or the scientists) to recognize this. The aliens appear to be under the biased impression that they are smarter than you. :P Someone cynical/foolish enough could also recommend the aliens to make sure they have a life...

Comment: @D.W., Marconius and everyone else: Please stop making and approving these edits that change the meaning of the question. Even if well-intentioned, the rules of the site (the relevant portion of which appears on the edit screen) clearly state that such major changes are for the OP to make, not you.

Comment: @epimorphic, I am familiar with the rules, and I disagree with your characterization of the edit.  My edit clarifies the question, not changes the meaning. The site rules specifically encourage edits. See http://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing ("Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so.") and http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit.

Comment: @epimorphic, I believe it is also relevant that the original poster was encouraged to provide clarification but hasn't edited the question; but [did respond](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242853/how-many-scientists-can-survive?noredirect=1#comment2527036_124297) in a way that suggests that speaking a number outside of the range 1-101 was likely not within the intent of the question.  I suggest we take any further discussion to Meta, to avoid overwhelming this comment thread -- if you still have concerns, would you post there?  Thank you for sharing your concerns.

Comment: @D.W. Apologies, I didn't see that comment by the OP to an answer, and I think there is certainly an exception to be made if they've implied that such a modification to the question should be made. I was frustrated seeing another edit vaguely similar in content to the one made by Marconius (which was removed by a moderator, and which I think you will agree is over the top). It was wrong of me to throw you in the lot. It would be helpful, I think, for edit summaries of such edits to specify that it was the OP who made the clarification.

Comment: @epimorphic, you are absolutely right, this should have been in the edit summary.  My apologies.  Thank you for being understanding.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can save 99.5 scientists.

Imagine that the 101st headband was left on the ground behind the first scientist, making a line of 101 headbands.

The strategy is that everyone should assume that the headbands are laid out in an even permutation of the numbers {1, 2, ..., 101}. Each scientist will always have a choice of two headbands: one results in an even permutation and one results in an odd permutation. They always make the choice which results in an even permutation.

If the headbands are actually in an even permutation (half the time), everyone guesses correctly. (More formal inductive proof below.)

If the headbands are actually in an odd permutation then the first scientist is dead. But the other scientists are still saved: they will end up naming a permutation which is correct except for the switch of the first scientist's headband with the one on the ground.

Proof that everyone guesses correctly if the headbands are actually in an even permutation:

Consider the first scientist. He can see 99 headbands, so he knows there are only two possible arrangements. These arrangements are related by a single swap (swapping his headband for the one left on the ground), so one of them is an even permutation and the other is odd. His strategy is to say the number which corresponds to the even permutation, and we're assuming here that it actually *is* an even permutation, so his guess is correct.

Now consider the nth scientist. We can assume for induction that the first (n-1) scientists have guessed correctly, and he can see a further (100-n) headbands. So he knows a total of 99 numbers. This means that, again, there are only two possible arrangements, and the two arrangements are related by a single swap (swapping his headband for the one on the ground). So precisely one of these arrangements is an even permutation, and this is the one that the nth scientist will guess. This means that the nth scientist has also guessed correctly, since we know that the actual arrangement is the even permutation.

Comment: Nice! All scientists after the first one are saved due to two wrongs making a right!

Comment: I do not understand this solution. Would you mind expanding on the "by induction part" and everything?

Comment: OK I've added a more formal version

Comment: This seems to assume that the erring scientists are killed instantly (and thus the others learn whether their predecessors were correct). The problem statemetnt says otherwise.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: No. If the first scientist is wrong, then the remaining scientists will assume he was right, and base their calculations off that. But they are also using the incorrect assumption that the permutation is even, and these two wrongs miraculously cancel out.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: the point is that collectively the scientists will all deduce the *same* permutation, and that permutation is correct except that it might have the back two headbands the wrong way around. That's the only mistake they can make. And 99 of the scientists aren't affected by that mistake. They don't need to know whether the scientists behind them were right, they only need to know what they said. Hearing that leaves them with two headbands to choose from (theirs, and one of the back two), and except for the first scientist they'll all choose their own.

Comment: Aye, now I see!

Answer (score 40):

The scientist in the rear states the sum of all 99 visible numbers, $S_{99}$. He or she will die. The second to last scientist is hopefully clever enough to understand why the prior scientist clearly picked a faulty number. This scientist can now can sum the 98 visible numbers, $S_{98}$, to uniquely determine his or her own number, $S_{99} - S_{98}$.

This idea is repeated, saving all the remaining scientists.

All but one survive.

Comment: This works if the scientist can say numbers above 101 which seems weird.

Comment: Since this makes it posible to communicate anything.

Comment: The only restriction I see is that they must state a number.

Comment: Ok, although if you can say any number the problemas males no sense, just give a number which produces a vídeo explaining what everyone mudt say when processed by a computer.

Comment: @Gamamal: That is effectively no different than this solution, since it still ends up with all the scientists living except for the one who gives the extra information. (Usually in problems like this, the victims are allowed time to collaborate. But that seems to not be the case here, in which case this solution becomes a lot less viable.)

Comment: My Point is there is no límit to the ammount of information.

Comment: @Gamamal Since we already know that the aliens are violent, it might not be a good idea to test their patience by attempting to convey too many megabytes of information orally.

Comment: New solution: One scientist begins to recite the digits of $\pi$. This filibuster is maintained until the space marines arrive.

Comment: @zahbaz Thanks for your solution. but I don't think that the scientists are able to say any number they want(though the question didn't say anything about it). Suppose that the number assigned to first scientist is a, second is b, third is c and so on, The last person could just say this number: a0b0c0d0... . so everybody (except the last person) would know his number.

Comment: Since $S_{99}-S_{98}$ is between 1 and 101, this solution also works if the scientists are only allowed to say a number between 1 and 101: simply compute all sums modulo 100 (taking the representative in $[1,101]$). Of course the scientists have to be able to elaborate their strategy beforehand, but that seems necessary for any solution as the current one.

Comment: But if the scientist are mathematicians, this solution will almost surely not work: it involves using and adding numbers greater than $3$, so errors are bound to occur.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner Your suggestion is my answer. Note that it only guarantees the survival of 98, though, for the reason stated in my answer.

Comment: @zahbaz in practice: "3 point... one?" http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=1777 Though I suppose you only need one of them to know more...

Comment: "hopefully clever enough" if they aren't, the 99 scientists die in confusion while the first one dies in vain.

Comment: But did you account for game theory? Is the first scientist's altruistic sense for the other $99$ larger than his or her desire for the $1/2$ chance to live that he or she has?

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I would like to tell you that I find your comment offensive. I have been trying to forget about it, but I still have not been able to do that.

Comment: @Quincunx: sorry to hear that. It was meant as a version of a classical joke, according to which mathematician are more comfortable with $n$ than with numbers greater than $3$. It might be worth adding that I am a mathematician myself.

Comment: @lino Thanks. Since the question is a bit open to interpretation, I'll stick to this answer with the justification that it's realistic, as in easily executable in such a scenario. I really enjoy Quincunx's workaround to fit such an answer into the acceptable range. David's permutation answer is also beautiful and unexpected. Those two answers require some degree of plotting, though, which again leaks info. If we have to restrict information and operate within the stated integer range, then WW1 probably has it correct in the comments: 50% death rate.

Answer (score 9):

Edit: Unfortunately, I forgot that $\oplus$ is only guaranteed to keep us within the number of bits, but we could still get higher. Instead, let's deal with modular arithmetic.

Suppose we have prisoners $N_1,\ldots,N_n$, where their numbers are $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_n$ (ie $n_i$ is the number of the scientist). For my purposes, suppose that we draw from the range $0, \ldots, n$ instead of $1, \ldots, n+1$ (it's trivial to convert from one range to the other). Also, let's define the order of the prisoners such that $N_i$ can see all $N_j$ such that $i>j$. Further, define the operator $\%$ such that $a\mathbin{\%}b = c$, where $c \equiv a \mod b$ and $c \in \{0,\ldots,b-1\}$. Okay.

Scientist $N_n$ computes $A_n=(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n_i)\mathbin{\%} n$ and says that.
Scientist $N_{n-1}$ computes $(A_n - (\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} n_i))\mathbin{\%} n = n_{n-1}$ and says that.
Scientist $N_j$ computes $(A_n - (\sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1} n_i) - (\sum_{i=0}^{i-1} n_i))\mathbin{\%} n = n_j$

And so each Scientist extracts their number. This results in a minimum of $98$ scientists living, since $99$ will figure out their numbers, but one might say the number said by $N_n$. Note that there is a chance, albeit small, that all $100$ scientists live.

---

The OP says that there is a way to save $99$ scientists. This would require $N_n$ to somehow encode the $2$ numbers he cannot see into just one of those $2$ numbers, so that $N_{n-1}$ can figure out his number. I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: This sounds really cool. I have little familiarity with this math, so unfortunately, I can't fully appreciate it. I wonder though, could this method potentially kill a second scientist? The scientists are not allowed to repeat a number. So say this method encodes the number as 77, then the scientist with headband 77 is doomed as well. Does it save 98 people then? Less?

Comment: @zahbaz oh, I forgot about that. Hmm. It would save at least 98 people.

Comment: Quincunx: When someone needs to say the number that the first scientist said, then what? He has to say something else, which messes up the calculation for everyone else.

Comment: @Samuel Well apparently the question meant something different than what I thought. I thought that repeating an already said number would result in the death of the repeat sayer; that was how I interpreted the question at the time of this answer

Answer (score 2):

Before the first person talks the second person has three potential options $a<b<c$ We will find a way so that the first person makes the second person have the correct answer (Of course the first person knows the three options the second person can have which are a,b or c. What we will do is that if the second person has $a$ he says $b$, if the second person has $b$ he says $c$ and if the second person has $c$ he says $a$. If person $1$ does this he can save person $2$, person $3$ can then do this to save person $4$ and so on. I don't think this is optimal but it may help. This method would save half the people when $n$ is even and slightly less than half when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

We can save $m$ scientists with $m$ to be determined below - and probably  more.
The numbers of the first $m$ scientists are known to the back $100-m$ scientists. Hence they all know the $101-m$ numbers distributed among them and the waste bin.
They compute a permutation of these $101-m$ numbers and anounce the first $100-m$ these in the order thus obtained. This allows them to convey $\log_2((100-m)!)$ bits of extra information to the front $m$ persons encoded in the permutation. Now each of the front $m$ scientists need only choose between two possible numbers, the only two numbers not yet heard and not seen by her. To make a decision, she extracts one bit from the extra information. In order to achieve that all $m$ can extract one bit, we need
$$ 2^m\le (100-m)!$$
This holds if we let $m=76$.

The permutation of $25$ numbers that the $24$ back scientists compute from looking at the first $m$ scientists can be considered random, hence has one fixed point on average and $\frac{24}{25}$ of this are scientists being saved. Thus

> 76 scientists guaranteed to be saved
>
> 76.96 scientists saved on average

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it may be because you saved such a small number of scientists compared with the other answers (and since you argued that 76 is optimal, there clearly must be something wrong with your reasoning).

Comment: @Brilliand Except implicitly by submitting my attempt in the first place,  I didn't say $76$ was optimal (it is merely the best choice for my *type* of approach). And *at the time of my writing* the better solutions were almost all flawed. But I agree that this answer is *now* very inferior. I guess I shall still keep it alive for its different approach

Answer (score 1):

**99 Scientists Saved**

The first scientist can deduce two possibilities for his number. If he makes a random guess, then the second scientist learns nothing and she will then also have a survival probability of only 50%. So clearly this will not work.

If, however, the first scientist sacrifices himself by somehow encoding the two possible numbers as a single number then all others will be able to deduce their numbers, so $99$ scientists will survive. One way of doing this for two numbers $x \ne y$ such that 
$$
1 \le x,y \le 101
$$
is for the first scientist to announce the product, $p$, of $10000+x$ and $10000+y$ which can be expanded as 
$$
p = (1000+x)(1000+y) = 100000000 + 10000(x+y) + xy. 
$$
The $10000$ is large enough that $xy < 10000$ unless $x$ and $y$ are the pair $100$ and $101$, which is easily dealt with as a special case.
In all other cases, the other scientists can recover the two numbers via the two equations:
$$
x + y = \lfloor \frac{p}{10000} \rfloor - 10000
$$
$$
xy = r
$$
where $r$ is the remainder of $p$ modulo $10000$.

For example, if the first scientist announces the product $100801311$
the two equations are 
$ x + y = 80 $ and $ xy = 1311 $
which are readily solved to give $23$ and $57$.

---

*Simpler encoding*

Or one could encode the two numbers as a concatenation of either number followed by the other number written as a three digit number (with leading zeroes if necessary), e.g. $23057$ or $57023$ in the example above.

Comment: It's not specified in the question, but the scientists should only be allowed to say a number between 1 and 101, or else the problem is trivial. See the comments to zahbaz's answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree: scientists should ony be able to guess integers between 1 and 101.

Answer (score 1):

**At Least 97 Scientists can be Saved**

*Assumptions - Additional Rules:*

- scientists can only guess integers between 1 and 101
- if a scientist says a number that has already been said, all scientists are killed

---

**First Scientist**

Can see $99$ other numbers, so can deduce his two possible numbers $x$ and $y$.
Announces a value $q=r+1$ where $r$ is the remainder of $x+y$ when divided by  $101$.
Hence $1 \le q \le 101$.

**Any Middle Scientist**
Assuming all previous middle scientists have guessed correctly, she has knowledge of 98 correct numbers (the first scientist is unlikely to be correct).
So she has to choose between three numbers: $a,b,c$. She must be able to find a pair, say $a,b$, such that
$$ a+b+1 \equiv q \quad (\textrm{mod} \quad 101)$$
since two of her possible numbers must be the same as the first scientist's.

Assume there is another such pair, say $a,c$. Then
$$ a+b+1 \equiv a+c+1 \quad (\textrm{mod} \quad 101) \quad \textrm{so} \quad b \equiv c \quad (\textrm{mod} \quad 101)$$
leading to $b=c$. So the assumption was false and there cannot be another distinct pair.

Since her number cannot be the same as either of the first scientist's possibilities (which are $a,b$), she is able to deduce her number ($c$).

*What then if that number was already said?*

Then the number must have been the one announced by the first scientist.

This unlucky middle scientist says the *number of the last scientist* (which cannot have been announced yet). Since all subsequent middle scientists are able to see the last scientist, each knows when this case has occurred and hence the *actual* number of this middle scientist. So then all other middle scientists can now assume that all prior middle guesses were correct, so are able to deduce their numbers. None can be blocked from saying their numbers.

**Last Scientist**

Can deduce his number by the same reasoning as for the middle scientists. If it has already been announced, he announces either of the two numbers that nobody has yet announced.

---

**Possible Outcomes**

*First Scientist:* survives only if the aliens removed the number $100$.

*Middle Scientists:* all survive if the aliens removed $100$, if the first scientist has $100$ (so says the number removed), or if he says the number of the last scientist. Otherwise, exactly one dies.

*Last Scientist:* survives only if the first scientist has $100$ (needs all middle scientists to survive) or if aliens removed $100$.